# Перекрытие окон в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Использую метод **Hide()** для скрытия окна.
До этого пользовался методом **Close()**, но из-за этого было много ошибок
Когда я снова вызываю окно (метод **Show()**), одно окно накладывается на другое и появляется эффект 2 или более записей на одном и том же месте
Можно от этого как-то избавится, не убирая метод **Hide()**?

Comment: Что такое "эффект двух и более записей"? Речь же шла про окно...

Comment: Это просто я так выразился

У меня появляется одно окно, потом накладывается еще одно
И в этих окнах разный текст

Comment: Не понятно в чем у вас проблема.

Comment: [Изображение](http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1507/2b/27d44edc3b97.png)

Вот, надеюсь я правильно ссылку добавил..

Comment: Без кода трудно. У вас в самом окне что-то делается? Есть подписка на события?

Comment: Я просто вызываю сначала одно окно, потом скрываю его, потом вызываю второе и появляется такое, как на скриншоте